# trying to call a parameterized oracle function by passing value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to call a parameter based function 'ABC' and trying to get the sum of all values returning through function while applying for loop in it, whose value is received from a cursor.

```
cursor so_count is
 select a.getno,a.getmno from mno a,pno b
  where a.idno=b.cdno and a.gls!='C' and b.countno in('12','10');

For h in so_count loop
 select To_Char(NVL(SUM(NVL(CRCSF006(a.getno,a.getmno ), 0)), 0)) as p from dual;
End Loop;
```

I am getting this error:

> component "getmno" must be declared "a.getno" invalid identifier.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: _If there is any syntax mistake_ then your PL/SQL code will not compile. So does it compile?

Comment: @Abra i have corrected and checked following error .

Comment: Here, You are doing the `SUM` but `Group by` is not used so `SUM` is irrelevant as it will do summation for only one record each time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong references. Intead of a it should be h. SO you query should ended up as -

```
SELECT To_Char(NVL(SUM(CRCSF006(h.getno,h.getmno)), 0)) as p
FROM dual;
```

Comment: @ankit i am trying to add the value in loop like this  For h in so_count loop LN_BAL_QNTY:=LN_BAL_QNTY + (select CRCSF006(h.iwi_wo_no,h.iwi_item_no) from dual;)   END LOOP; but getting error PLS-00103 encountered symbol select any idea how to add value in the variable.

Comment: First you need to assign the select value into a variable and then use that variable while adding the values. Select queries doesn't work in PL/SQL.

Comment: i am trying like this as you suggest but not getting blank value is it right   For h in so_count loop select CRCSF006(h.iwi_wo_no,h.iwi_item_no) into W from dual ;  LN_BAL_QNTY:=LN_BAL_QNTY + W;   END LOOP;

Comment: Are you sure your select query is giving you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it using a single select query as following:

```
SELECT
--    TO_CHAR(NVL(SUM(NVL(CRCSF006(A.GETNO, A.GETMNO), 0)), 0)) AS P
    TO_CHAR(NVL(SUM(CRCSF006(A.GETNO, A.GETMNO)), 0)) 
    INTO LN_BAL_QNTY
FROM
    MNO A
    JOIN PNO B ON A.IDNO = B.CDNO
WHERE
    A.GLS != 'C'
    AND B.COUNTNO IN ('12','10');
```

Tip for the day: Always use the **standard ANSI joins**.

Cheers!!